# Symfony2 Entity findAll()

Tags: symfony, doctrine, findall

I have database table with 7 rows, I'am trying to fetch those rows with findAll function

```
$machine_current_counter_repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('DummyMonitorBundle:MachineCurrentCounter');

$counters = $machine_current_counter_repo->findAll();
```

The result is 7 rows, but all rows contain data from the first row.

Here is [database table entity.](http://pastebin.com/CbnYkvhZ)

And table structure:

```
`machine_current_counter` (
  `machine_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `counter_value` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `time_stamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`machine_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What could cause this problem?

Ps. Entity is generated from database so by default first column setup was this (not sure why type was "boolean", but I changes it to integer, still that didn't solved the problem):

```
/**
 * @var boolean
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="machine_id", type="boolean")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $machineId;
```

Comment: Strange.. Recreate the schema, insert data and test again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@ORM\Id** means values of this field MUST be unique. With the boolean type they can be unique only in 2 or less row (because boolean has only 2 values - 0 and 1).
I think you have logical mistake, and must simply change type of field to integer. Like that:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="machine_id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $machineId;
```

Then update your schema by **./app/console doctrine:schema:update** then recreate data into table.

Comment: I solved this by as you say changing types, and manually altering table to `machine_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL, from `machine_id` `machine_id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,. Although now that I think off it ./app/console doctrine:schema:update would have probably done the same.

Comment: You must change info into mapped entity, rather than directly into sql server. This will cause alot of errors in future. For example, when you will uptade your database schema, it will try to back to tinyint(3)